# Express session is not keeping its data

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I have a mern web app, and I'm using express session. The problem is, the cookie data is not getting saved when I try retrieving it on a different route. It gets set and outputs correctly on the same route, but when I go to another route, and try to retrieve the session data, it returns `undefined`.

What's weird, is that the session does get stored in mongodb, but I can't retrieve it.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Here's the relevant code:

**Session.js**

```
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = function(app) {
    var sess = {
        secret: 'mySecret',
        cookie: { token: null },
        saveUninitialized: false,
        resave: true,
        store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
    };

    if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
        app.set('trust proxy', 1);
        sess.cookie.secure = true;
    }

    app.use(session(sess));
};
```

**Route.js**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(helmet());
    require('../middleware/session')(app);
    // Other routes...
};
```

**File1**

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    req.session.token = 'hello';
    console.log(req.session.token); // Outputs 'hello'
    res.send(req.session.token);
});
```

**File2** This gets called After the page reloads

```
router.get('/me', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session.token); // Outputs undefined
    console.log(req.session);
// Outputs: "Session {
// cookie: { path: '/',                                                    
// _expires:null,
// originalMaxAge: null,
// httpOnly: true }
// }

    res.send(req.session.token);
});
```

Comment: I have used your code to make one example, and it is working fine. Just in `res.send(token);` there is no `token` variable declared.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty Ya, that was a typo... When you do the log, is token undefined, or do u get the actual value?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty Also, the /me route gets called after the page reloads

Comment: Yes I get the Actual value. Page reload doesn't matter. I am doing two calls from my postman.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty Interesting.. I'm using MERN. So maybe that's what's causing it?

Comment: Try with postman and check if it works.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty Just realized that express-session is creating a new session or mongo document on every page reload. Trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the code below in your app.js file

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({secret: "Funny secret"}));
```

That's the simple way to do it. Then you may be able to assign and access values to the **req.session** object.

Comment: Hey James! Thanks for the answer, but I don't think it's correct for two reasons. 1: I can access req.session object. it's just that the session gets created after every page reload. 2: the docs say since version 1.5.0, cookie-parser is not required